# Browse Decision Table in WODM or iLog

Tags: ilog

I have a situation that I have a system that communicate with iLog and it should show the values of decision table first column.

Can I get all the values of the first column in a decision table? Given that the values are distinct and unique.

If yes, What if I want to get the values of the next column under the scope of the first column field.

I need this behavior since I have an agreement creation system which must allow creation of agreement terms based on what is already implemented in iLog

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to extract values from Condition Column. I had also came across such situation when but couldn't get through it. However, there is a work-around for the same.

My Problem was, for example, there are rules to determine whether the user group to which user belong is allowed to approve the policy? If not, then what are the other user groups allowed to approve this policy?

One simple solution was to maintain two tables, one for checking and another to determine allowed groups. This was not accepted since business needs to maintain same data in two tables. Had it been FICO BLAZE Advisor, the same would have been implemented in a single table.

However, there is always another way to a problem. What I did is following:
1. Created a single table to list all are the groups which can approve the policy i.e. adding user groups into a list in the action column. Placed this decision table in a Rule Task.
2. In the final action of rule task, checked whether the user type of the incoming user exists in the list of user types. If not, it means user is not allowed to approve the policy so send the entire list; otherwise, set the list to null and set Approval flag to True.

I hope this may help you to find an alternate solution which may address your problem. Sometimes, we need to look for some weird way to get our work done.

HAPPY RULE DEVELOPMENT. :)

Comment: Well, I do really appreciated your response. I voted up to you since I didn't get a response long time ago. However, My situation is much more complex. Basically, Im not rules dev rather Im java dev and iLog team told me that they can't do the requirement as you said but they don't won't to spend some effort as you do to find work arounds. Finally, we are in a deadlock. Well, as the famous saying "no one will scratch your back better than you do", I decided to read about JESS and DROOLS to see which one can be embedded in my java application.

Comment: iLog\WODM has more advantages when compared to other rule engines however it's not as flexible as FICO Blaze Advisor. Sometimes we real look for an alternate solution. Best of luck for Drools.

Comment: Decided to go with Jess. It's easy to learn, very fast and super powerful too. I can embed it in my java ee application and make my rules in an external .clp file. I guess that I found my choice. Thanks for your help